# How do I retrieve every file with a HTTP 200 response code in a certain directory with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to retrieve every PDF file of the Universal Declaration of Human Rights, which is found in English [here](http://www.ohchr.org/EN/UDHR/Documents/UDHR_Translations/eng.pdf).

As you can see, the file path includes ".../UDHR_Translations/**eng**.pdf". I want to download every version of the PDF file, a-z, that returns an HTTP 200 response code. Without checking for the HTTP 200 response code, there is 17576 possible versions (26^3).

How do I do this in Python? A loop function checking for HTTP 200 response codes, then downloading the ones that come back with it? Can I have an example code of this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey.. this is a fairly large question to write answer for there's lots of concepts.. I'm writing the answer, wait for my solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is highly specific and it contains the application of many concepts. I get the feeling you have not learned python yet and need a ready made solution. Hope this helps you out and get a flavor of the language, ask me if you need more explanation I will add it for you!

```
import urllib2
import string
import itertools
import os

chars, filenames = string.lowercase, []
for r in itertools.product(chars, chars, chars):
    filenames.append(r[0] + r[1] + r[2])

# filenames will now contain an array like
# [aaa, aab, aac, aad, aae, ... , zzx, zzy, zzz]

print("Number of filenames: " + str(len(filenames)))

# Uncomment the line below for testing before you run it for all filenames
# filenames = ['eng']

# Change your directory relative to current directory here
save_to = os.path.abspath("pdfs/")

for f in filenames:
    url = 'http://www.ohchr.org/EN/UDHR/Documents/UDHR_Translations/' + f + '.pdf'
    print('Requesting: ' + url)

    # Setup urllib2 Request
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    req.add_header('User-Agent', 'some fake agent string')
    req.add_header('Referer', 'fake referrer')

    # Get status code first and if status is 200 get response
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=4)
        status = response.getcode()
        # If 200 status found
        if status == 200:
            print('PDF File found at: ' + f + ' ' + url)
            print('Saving..')
            # Write in Binary mode as files are PDF
            f = open(save_to + '/' + f + '.pdf', 'wb')
            f.write(response.read())
            f.close() # Dont forget to close the file
            print('Saved.')
        else:
            print('Status was not 200 OK: ' + f + ' ' + url)
    except urllib2.HTTPError: # 404 error
        print('No file found: ' + f + ' ' + url)
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really experienced in python (I've completed the Codecademy course, if that counts for anything)  and I've contributed to some software on GitHub. I do appreciate your help though, and I apologize for the extremely specific question.